# Horror short story with a spider lady, a motel, and tap shoes

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A couple of years ago I read a short scifi/horror story and I'm searching for the title. It was about a person who went to a motel and had weird noises coming from the other room.

When investigated, the noise was coming from a woman with eight legs like a spider, wearing tap shoes. Can anyone help identify the possible title or author?

Comment: This is an amazingly odd story premise, and I hope we find a solution eventually...